# How to disable response caching for all controllers in ASP.NET Core MVC, but keep for static files?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I have app which call html/json requests by same URL, vary it with `Accept` request header.

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

[ActionName(nameof(Index))]
[AcceptHeader(MediaTypeNames.Application.Json)]
public async Task<IActionResult> IndexJson()
{
    // ...some kind of magic here.

    return Json(model);
}
```

It works, but when there is no `app.UseResponseCaching()` defined in `Startup.cs` and ajax request performed (no `Content-Control` header in response), browser remember last json response whith given URL and shows it raw on white screen instead of making new request for html-version while navigating in history back/forward.

The quick fix for prevent caching (tested, no raw anymore):

```
[ResponseCache(NoStore = true, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None)]
public class HomeController { ...
```

But I do not want to define this attribute manually on all controllers. How to set this rule in ConfigureServices for dynamic output by default while keep caching for static files?

Comment: afaik you can set cache: false in the ajax request to disable super caching (not sure if this solves your problem,though)